# nulls and dbnull is there more efficient syntax

Tags: c#-3.0

I am trying to use the solution given here ->

[C# ADO.NET: nulls and DbNull -- is there more efficient syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218808/c-ado-net-nulls-and-dbnull-is-there-more-efficient-syntax)

But I am working with an int.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int? myNullableInt = null;
myIntParameter.Value = myNullableInt ?? (object)DBNull.Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Substitute `int?` for `DateTime?` then...