# C# ?? null coalescing operator

Tags: c#, dbnull, null-coalescing-operator

I have defined Class **Person** property **Birthday** as **nullable DateTime?** , so why shouldn’t the null coalescing operator work in the following example?

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Birthday",
   SqlDbType.SmallDateTime)).Value =       
     person.Birthday ?? DBNull.Value;
```

The compiler err I got was "Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.DateTime?' and 'System.DBNull'"

The following also got a compile error :

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Birthday", 
  SqlDbType.SmallDateTime)).Value = 
   (person.Birthday == null) ? person.Birthday:DBNull.Value;
```

I added a cast to (object)  as recommended by Refactor, and it compiled, but didn’t work properly and the value was stored in the sqlserver db as null in both cases.

```
SqlDbType.SmallDateTime)).Value =       
         person.Birthday ?? (object)DBNull.Value;
```

Can someone explain  what is going on here?

I needed to use the following clumsy code:

```
   if (person.Birthday == null) 
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Birthday", SqlDbType.SmallDateTime).Value 
      = DBNull.Value;
     else cmd.Parameters.Add("@Birthday", SqlDbType.SmallDateTime).Value = 
          person.Birthday;
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218808/c-ado-net-nulls-and-dbnull-is-there-more-efficient-syntax

Comment: Got this from the other post: SqlDbType.SmallDateTime)).Value = person.Birthday ?? (object)DBNull.Value;  Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The problem is that `DateTime?` and `DBNull.Value` are not the same type so you can't use the null coalescing operator on them.

In your case you can do `person.Birthday ?? (object)DBNull.Value` to pass a value of type `object` through to `Add()`

Answer (score 5):

I prefer to iterate over my parameters just before executing the query, changing all instances of null to DBNull as appropriate, for example:

```
foreach (IDataParameter param in cmd.Parameters)
    if (param.Value == null)
        param.Value = DBNull.Value;
```

This lets me leave null values as-is and simply swap them out en masse later.

Comment: My issue with this is the extra overhead of iterating over the parameters after the fact, versus handling them immediately.

Answer (score 3):

Your first problem is that for the `??` or `?:` operator, the objects for either choice must be the same type.  Here they are different type.

Comment: So what does `?:` do?  edit: nevermind, I knew that, just never saw those 2 symbols put together like that before.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx